# How to send a urllib2 request with added white spaces

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to send a request to open web page url that uses white spaces so that I can download a file from the page. 
In a normal browser i.e chrome when you enter the url into the address bar the file is automatically generated and you are asked to download it.

Instead of having to load a web browser every time I want a set of logs I am trying to create a python script that I can run that will do all the hard work for me.

Example:

```
url = http (ip-address)/supportlog.xml/getlogs&name=0335008 04-05-2013 12.46.47.zip
```

Im using the command:

```
xml_page = opener.open((url))
```

I have been able to to download other zip files fine from the web sever I am connecting to, using the following command and some other lines of code.

But when i try the same command with the url with added white spaces.

urllib2 knocks off all of the white spaces meaning I get a syntax error back. 
Ideally you would change the url not to contain white spaces, but this isn't possible.

I have tried addressing the URL with %20 to replace the white spaces but this doesn't work and causes the sever to fail.

I understand you can use the `urllib.quote` tool, but not sure how to or even if this is the correct pass to go down.

Any help is welcome... I'm still learning python so please be kind.

Comment: This answer works for me:
[I get InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters when I try to send a request using urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64521219/i-get-invalidurl-url-cant-contain-control-characters-when-i-try-to-send-a-requ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to clean your url with whitespaces use `urllib.quote` like this:

```
import urllib
url = urllib.quote("http://www.example.com/a url with whitespaces")
```

To download a file to cannot use functions like `urllib2.urlopen`. If you want to download a file using the `urllib` modules you need `urllib.urlretrieve`. However, `requests` is easier to grasp in the beginning.

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url)
```

The `response` provides several useful functions:

- `response.text`: The source code of the website or the content of the downloaded file.
- `response.status_code`: Status code of your request. 200 is ok.

You probably want to save your downloaded file somewhere. So open a file connection with `open` in *binary* mode and write the content of your response. Do not forget to close the file.

```
your_file_connection = open('your_file', 'wb')
your_file_connection.save(response.text)
your_file_connection.flush()
your_file_connection.close()
```

**Summary**

```
import urllib
import requests

url = urllib.quote("http://www.example.com/a url with whitespaces")
response = requests.get(url)

your_file_connection = open('your_file', 'wb')
your_file_connection.save(response.text)
your_file_connection.
your_file_connection.close()
```

`requests` Documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you! 

I just have one question in relation to your response.

When I send the get command I get the following back.

'No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant [link]http://www.example.com/ a url with whitespaces? is not a valid integer'.

I have had a good look at the documentation and around the web but I cant seam to find anything that helps.

Thank you!

Comment: Dont worry, after many hours and large amounts of coffee I found the solution.

For those interested the issue was that the quote function was adding in white space characters in places not required. The trick was to split the full url into white space and non white space.



url_main = http://www.exampledomain.com

url_lower = /a white space url

Then combine and put into the request function 

thanks

Comment: Works! Except that response.status should be response.status_code and response.content should be response.text (According to http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in Python 3.X anymore (see new answer below)

Answer (score 3):

While the answer of Jon was then the correct way, note that in Python 3.X you have to change it to:

```
import urllib.parse
url = urllib.parse.quote("http://www.example.com/a url with whitespaces"')
```

Answer (score 0):

After attempting this, I figured out that the line:
your_file_connection.save(response.content)

needs to be:
your_file_connection.write(response.content)

at least on Python 2.*