# Was working before but not getting urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I haven't changed my code, but now when I try to run it, I am getting

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

On this line

```
response = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
```

The url is

```
url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/f8cb961c53baad52/geolookup/conditions/q/{}/{}.json'.format(state.strip(), city)
```

Should I wait until later and try again since it was working until just an hour ago.

EDIT:

I am using Python 3.5 and have changed to

```
url = quote("http://api.wunderground.com/api/f8cb961c53baad52/geolookup/conditions/q/{}/{}.json").format(state.strip(), city)
```

This results in the url

```
http%3A//api.wunderground.com/api/f8cb961c53baad52/geolookup/conditions/q/%7B%7D/%7B%7D.json
```

And the error message

```
ValueError: unknown url type: 'http%3A//api.wunderground.com/api/f8cb961c53baad52/geolookup/conditions/q/%7B%7D/%7B%7D.json'
```

EDIT 2:

I have used

```
url = 'api.wunderground.com/api/f8cb961c53baad52/geolookup/conditions/q/{}/{}.json'.format(state.strip(), city)
print (url)
url1 = quote(url)
url2 = 'http://'+ url1
```

To encode the spaces but I am still getting the 400 error . I will wait until tomorrow and try again as perhaps there's an issue with my access.

EDIT: 
It is working with cities without the spaces. So I will keep trying to get the ones with spaces working on my own. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think it's more likely that your `url` variable was not formatted correctly. That's the [meaning of HTTP error 400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes): the service received the request but couldn't understand it. Before calling urlopen(), print `url` to verify that the state and city are interpolated as you expect.

Comment: I am already doing that and I got this http://api.wunderground.com/api/f8cb961c53baad52/geolookup/conditions/q/ID/Boise City.json When I went to that url myself it opened without an issue. But now with any city I've been trying my file isn't working.

Comment: You should encode your variables with `urllib.quote()` because spaces in the url will mess up urlopen. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735801/how-to-send-a-urllib2-request-with-added-white-spaces

Comment: Thanks. I just realized the city has spaces in it.

Comment: I am using Python 3.5 and now when I try it I get this url http%3A//api.wunderground.com/api/f8cb961c53baad52/geolookup/conditions/q/%7B%7D/%7B%7D.json which gives an error of unknown url type. url = quote("http://api.wunderground.com/api/f8cb961c53baad52/geolookup/conditions/q/{}/{}.json").format(state.strip(), city)

Comment: Just quote path portion of the URL, not the entire thing.  So something like: `url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/f8cb961c53baad52/geolookup/conditions/q/{}/{}.json".format(quote(state.strip()), quote(city))`

Answer (score 0):

Just paste a sample URL query in your web browser and based on the response you might find out that you have either over used the API or they have blocked you due to terms of use. I tested it and it works for me.

EDIT: PYTHON 3.5 working!

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/f8cb961c53baad52/geolookup/conditions/q/{}/{}.json".format('AZ', 'Chandler')
response = requests.get(url=url)
response.json()
```

Output:

{'current_observation': {'UV': '0',
  'dewpoint_c': 5,
  'dewpoint_f': 41,
  'dewpoint_string': '41 F (5 C)',
  'display_location': {'city': 'Chandler',
   'country': 'US',
   'country_iso3166': 'US',
   ....

Comment: I thought that might also be the problem but when I went to the admin function for that site, I didn't see that I had made too many calls to their api. But I will wait until tomorrow and try again. Thanks.

Comment: RATE LIMITS; OVERAGE POLICY. 
(a.)KEY; MONITORING. There is a daily limit and minute rate limit to the number of requests that can be made to the API for free. You may exceed this threshold only if you are or become a fee paying subscriber. WUL will monitor your daily usage of the API to determine if you have exceeded the free-use threshold by using an application programming interface key (the “Key”). Refer to the “Key Settings” page for product pricing, package features, and rate limit levels.

Comment: I didn't think I was over the limit, because before I got an email saying I had gone over and this time I didn't get anything.

Comment: If I exceed the limit I would get Request Denial - Surpassed rate limit"  and I wasn't getting that.

Comment: @Sam I have updated my answer and it is working for me in python 3.5.

Comment: The issue seems to be with cities that have a space in them. The other ones work fine. So I have to escape the spaces.