# I get InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters when I try to send a request using urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to get a JSON response from the link used as a parameter to the urllib request. but it gives me an error that it can't contain control characters.

how can I solve the issue?

```
start_url = "https://devbusiness.un.org/solr-sitesearch-output/10//0/ds_field_last_updated/desc?bundle_fq =procurement_notice&sm_vid_Institutions_fq=&sm_vid_Procurement_Type_fq=&sm_vid_Countries_fq=&sm_vid_Sectors_fq= &sm_vid_Languages_fq=English&sm_vid_Notice_Type_fq=&deadline_multifield_fq=&ts_field_project_name_fq=&label_fq=&sm_field_db_ref_no__fq=&sm_field_loan_no__fq=&dm_field_deadlineFrom_fq=&dm_field_deadlineTo_fq =&ds_field_future_posting_dateFrom_fq=&ds_field_future_posting_dateTo_fq=&bm_field_individual_consulting_fq="
    
source = urllib.request.urlopen(start_url).read()
```

the error I get is :

```
URL can't contain control characters. '/solr-sitesearch-output/10//0/ds_field_last_updated/desc?bundle_fq =procurement_notice&sm_vid_Institutions_fq=&sm_vid_Procurement_Type_fq=&sm_vid_Countries_fq=&sm_vid_Sectors_fq= &sm_vid_Languages_fq=English&sm_vid_Notice_Type_fq=&deadline_multifield_fq=&ts_field_project_name_fq=&label_fq=&sm_field_db_ref_no__fq=&sm_field_loan_no__fq=&dm_field_deadlineFrom_fq=&dm_field_deadlineTo_fq =&ds_field_future_posting_dateFrom_fq=&ds_field_future_posting_dateTo_fq=&bm_field_individual_consulting_fq=' (found at least ' ')
```

Comment: Is it a valid URL? It doesn't work from a browser and has a strange part `/10//0/ `. Normally, double-slash `//` can be replaced with a single slash, then the URL gives page not found.

Comment: you are right, I provided the wrong URL, i Fixed it. thank you. small mistakes are always big headaches.

Comment: please make sure you encode you urls: https://www.urlencoder.io/python/ actually in url, " " should be "%20" or "+"

Comment: Looks like a unprintable character slipped into the URL somehow.

Answer (score 24):

Replacing whitespace with:

```
url = url.replace(" ", "%20")
```

if the problem is with the whitespace.

Comment: so simple  and do the job

Answer (score 5):

Spaces are not allowed in URL, I removed them and it seems to be working now:

```
import urllib.request
start_url = "https://devbusiness.un.org/solr-sitesearch-output/10//0/ds_field_last_updated/desc?bundle_fq =procurement_notice&sm_vid_Institutions_fq=&sm_vid_Procurement_Type_fq=&sm_vid_Countries_fq=&sm_vid_Sectors_fq= &sm_vid_Languages_fq=English&sm_vid_Notice_Type_fq=&deadline_multifield_fq=&ts_field_project_name_fq=&label_fq=&sm_field_db_ref_no__fq=&sm_field_loan_no__fq=&dm_field_deadlineFrom_fq=&dm_field_deadlineTo_fq =&ds_field_future_posting_dateFrom_fq=&ds_field_future_posting_dateTo_fq=&bm_field_individual_consulting_fq="
url = start_url.replace(" ","")
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

Answer (score 4):

Solr search strings can get pretty weird. Better use the 'quote' method to encode characters before making the request. See example below:

```
from urllib.parse import quote

start_url = "https://devbusiness.un.org/solr-sitesearch-output/10//0/ds_field_last_updated/desc?bundle_fq =procurement_notice&sm_vid_Institutions_fq=&sm_vid_Procurement_Type_fq=&sm_vid_Countries_fq=&sm_vid_Sectors_fq= &sm_vid_Languages_fq=English&sm_vid_Notice_Type_fq=&deadline_multifield_fq=&ts_field_project_name_fq=&label_fq=&sm_field_db_ref_no__fq=&sm_field_loan_no__fq=&dm_field_deadlineFrom_fq=&dm_field_deadlineTo_fq =&ds_field_future_posting_dateFrom_fq=&ds_field_future_posting_dateTo_fq=&bm_field_individual_consulting_fq="
    
source = urllib.request.urlopen(quote(start_url)).read()
```

Better later than never...

Comment: `urlopen` raises the ValueError exception, because it also escapes the colon separator after https. Better to use `urlparse` on the url first, and then use `quote` only what is needed.

Comment: See my suggested answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74827725/9075334

Answer (score 2):

You probably already found out by now but let's get it written here.

There can't be any *space* character in the URL, and there are 2, after **bundle_fq** e **dm_field_deadlineTo_fq**

Remove those and you're good to go

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the url first and then encoding the url elements would work.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse, quote

def make_safe_url(url: str) -> str:
    """
    Returns a parsed and quoted url
    """
    _url = urlparse(url)
    url = _url.scheme + "://" + _url.netloc + quote(_url.path) + "?" + quote(_url.query)
    return url

start_url = "https://devbusiness.un.org/solr-sitesearch-output/10//0/ds_field_last_updated/desc?bundle_fq =procurement_notice&sm_vid_Institutions_fq=&sm_vid_Procurement_Type_fq=&sm_vid_Countries_fq=&sm_vid_Sectors_fq= &sm_vid_Languages_fq=English&sm_vid_Notice_Type_fq=&deadline_multifield_fq=&ts_field_project_name_fq=&label_fq=&sm_field_db_ref_no__fq=&sm_field_loan_no__fq=&dm_field_deadlineFrom_fq=&dm_field_deadlineTo_fq =&ds_field_future_posting_dateFrom_fq=&ds_field_future_posting_dateTo_fq=&bm_field_individual_consulting_fq="
start_url = make_safe_url(start_url)
source = urllib.request.urlopen(start_url).read()
```

The code returns the JSON-document despite the double forward-slash and the whitespace in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, there are some [control characters](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp) in your url, which doesn't seem to be a valid one by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [encode the control characters](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) inside the URL. Especially spaces need to be encoded to %20.

Answer (score -2):

Please check the proxy address is there any ***Blank Space***,

Due to blank space, we are getting this error.

Comment: This was already said more than 1 year ago